# How are two matrices similar?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, education, similar-matrices

I am aware that this question has been asked before, but I would like to see if anyone can come up with a better explanation.

So what I have been stuck on is, what are the requirements for two matrices to be similar.

I know that Matrix A and B are similar if the following is true: $A = V^{-1} \cdot B \cdot V$ But how in the world do I find V.

It is one thing to determain V, but how do I know that such a vector exists. In other words, what is the requirements for two matrices to be similar.

Comment: Google eigenvalues, eigenvectors, diagonalizability, Jordan canonical form, and finally the rational canonical form (this is the one which works over all fields).

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it. But if it isnt to much trouble, would you mind explaining what determines if two matrices are similar?

Comment: Two square matrices of the same size are similar if and only if they have the same rational canonical form. But the RCF is usually the more “difficult” (i.e lots more algebra to learn) thing to deal with hence why we usually settle for the JCF (in case the field is algebraically closed) or merely eigenvalues to quickly tell us when  two matrices are (not) similar.